# Select a value into a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following statement:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("dropCity", new[] { new SelectlistItem { Text = "City1", Value = 1}, new SelectlistItem { Text = "City2", Value = 2}, new SelectlistItem { Text = "City3", Value = 3}})%>
```

Suppous that my controller sent to the aspx page that contais this dropdownlist a variable with the value "3", how can I set this dropdownlist to select this option when the page loads ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use view models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCityId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

then have your controller populate this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        // preselect the second city
        SelectedCityId = "2",
        Cities = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "City1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "City2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "City3" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, Model.Cities) %>
```

Comment: @Dan-SP, in ASP.NET MVC the recommended approach is to always use view models. Always.

Answer (score 1):

If your controller is passing '3' why not making it pass the all list of SelectListItem instead?

Then you would do something like this in or controller:

```
public ActionResult MyController(MyModel model) 
{
    // Build SelectListItem list
    ViewBag.CitiesList = new List<SelectListItem>() 
    {
        new SelectlistItem { Text = "City1", Value = 1, Selected = true}, 
        new SelectlistItem { Text = "City2", Value = 2}, 
        new SelectlistItem { Text = "City3", Value = 3}
    }

    View(model);
}
```

And received it this way within the view:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("dropCity", ViewBag.CitiesList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) %>
```

This way the all logic behind selecting the proper city is in the controller, as it should since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the selectlistitem, just do:

```
new SelectlistItem { Text = "City1", Value = 1, Selected=true}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("dropCity", new[] { 
      new SelectlistItem { Text = "City1", Value = 1, Selected = true}, 
      new SelectlistItem { Text = "City2", Value = 2}, 
      new SelectlistItem { Text = "City3", Value = 3}})%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response ! The problem is that I don't know the option that is coming from the controller.. It could be 1 one time.. on the other refresh it could be 2.. or 3..

Comment: @Dan-SP - I don't understand your problem.  You know the value coming from the controller because it's coming from the controller. Do something like Selected = myvalue == 1, selected = myvalue == 2, etc..

Comment: Its coming from the controller, thats why I can't set "Text = "City1", Value = 1, Selected = true" because on any other situation I can get value 2 comming from controller..

Comment: @Dan-SP - It's not very helpful if you want us to provide a solution that is different from the code sample you provided.  You asked fore a solution to your hard coded value problem.  If your real code is not hard coded, then provide a sample that shows your real code, otherwise we're just wasting our time.

Comment: Thats the real code. I got some other samples but I use a model with them, and with this It works nicelly. The problem is that I wont use a model with the case I showed with my problem, check: <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.code, new SelectList(Model.dropDwonList, "Code", "Name", VALUE_FROM_CONTROLLER), "Select One Option", new { style = "width:180px"})%>